# Unite multiple code lines into one function in sml/ml using "let" command

Tags: grouping, sml, func, ml, let

I'm having a problem grouping these code lines into one function

```
sumFirstEven : int * int seq -> int
```

such that `sumFirstEven (5, s)` is the sum of the first 5 even elements of the sequence s

I've been told that I need to group my lines into one function that includes "let-in commands"

these are my lines for these func:

```
datatype 'a seq=null|SEQ of 'a*(unit->'a seq);

fun head(SEQ(x,_))=x
|head null=raise Empty;

fun tail(SEQ(_,xf))=xf()
|tail null=raise Empty;


fun sumFirstEven(0,_)=0
|sumFirstEven(n,null)=0
|sumFirstEven(n,xs)=if(head(xs) mod 2=0)then head(xs)+sumFirstEven(n-1,tail(xs))
else sumFirstEven(n,tail(xs));

fun seqFrom i=SEQ(i,fn()=>seqFrom(i+1));
val seqStart=seqFrom 1;

sumFirstEven(5,seqStart);
```

My function works fine but I dont know how to regroup all of these lines
 correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The beauty of pattern matching is that it often obviates helper functions like `head` and `tail`.

```
fun sumFirstEven (0, _) = 0
  | sumFirstEven (_, null) = 0
  | sumFirstEven (n, SEQ (h, t)) =
      case h mod 2
        of 0 => h + sumFirstEven (n-1, t ())
         | _ => sumFirstEven (n, t ())
```

Since the first two clauses didn't match, there's no need in the third clause to call a function with a failure condition like `head`... we already know the data is in the right form!

The pattern matching in the function clause serves the same role that a `let-in-end` expression (not command!) would.

Answer (score 1):

Given your lazy list type,

```
datatype 'a seq = Null | Seq of 'a * (unit -> 'a seq)
```

you might want the helper function,

```
fun even n = n mod 2 = 0
```

and you might want to either recurse manually,

```
fun sumFirstEven (0, _) = 0
  | sumFirstEven (_, Null) = 0
  | sumFirstEven (n, Seq (x, seqf) =
      if even x
      then x + sumFirstEven (n-1, seqf ())
      else sumFirstEven (n, seqf ())
```

or you may want to accumulate the result in a function parameter,

```
fun sumFirstEven (n, seq) =
    let fun sfe (0, _, result) = result
          | sfe (_, Null, result) = result
          | sfe (n, Seq (x, seqf), result) =
              if even x
              then sfe (n-1, seqf (), result + x)
              else sfe (n, seqf (), result)
    in sfe (n, seq, 0) end
```

to make it tail-recursive (i.e. use a fixed amount of stack frames). More conveniently, you might want to extract the recursion part of the function into a separate higher-order fold combinator,

```
fun foldseqn _ e 0 _ = e
  | foldseqn _ e _ Null = e
  | foldseqn f e n (Seq (x, seqf)) =
      case f (x, e) of
          (e', true) => foldseqn f e' (n-1) (seqf ())
        | (e', false) => foldseqn f e' n (seqf ())

fun sumFirstEven (n, seq) =
      foldseqn (fn (x, sum) => if even x
                               then (sum + x, true)
                               else (sum, false)) 0 n seq
```

And a quick test,

```
fun nats n = Seq (n, fn () => nats (n+1))
val twelve = sumFirstEven (3, nats 1) (* 2+4+6 *)
```

**Edit:** Responded to Nick's comment, thanks.

Comment: In your case, `sumFirstEven (n, seq)` won't evaluate to the sum of the first `n` even elements but rather the sum of the even members of the first `n` elements of the sequences.